# Using django Authentication form with the html form

Tags: html, django, forms, authentication

I am trying to build a login module in django. I already have a nice **HTML form** for login which has username and password field.

But in my views.py I have imported default  Django **AuthenticationForm**, but if integrate it with my nice-looking HTML form, there will be two forms. How can I import the Authentication form and use it with the my HTML form??

My **code** is here:

My view:

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.get_user()
            authlog(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Invalid username or password')
            # back_page = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
            return redirect('login')
            
            # return HttpResponse(back_page)
    else:
        content = {
            'form': AuthenticationForm()
        }
        return render(request, 'sign-in.html', content)
```

If I use Django default form, the code will be following, but it won't look good as my other Html login page.

My **sign-in** html:

```
<hr>
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form|crispy}}
    <button type="submit" class=" btn btn-success ">Sign-Up</button>

</form>
```

I haven't posted my other HTML form though as it is very large. Hope it explains.

Comment: What is the purpose of your custom form? The default Django form, has all the fields you need in order to login. You can use that form and style it as you like in your template.

Comment: My custom fields have all the styles and images and svgs needed. And it has all the classes, but I how can I style my default form like that {{form|crispy}}?? Cant I just put {{form|crispy}} inside the custom form??

Comment: you can add css class to your form within widget, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/50524134/11225821