# Assigning a Class for a label in the Django forms

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to add a class for label in a custom django form. I am able to add class to the input but for the labels I have been struggling for a while:

Here is the form:

```
class infoForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Info
        fields = ['businessName']
        widgets={
            'businessName':forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": 'form-control'}),
        }
        labels = {
            'businessName': 'Business Name',
        }
```

Here is the model

```
class Info(models.Model):
    businessName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

***My question:***

**How to add the class `form-label` inside the label of every input?**
Thank you

Comment: Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29716023/add-class-to-form-field-django-modelform)