# Change layout of django-filter form

Tags: python, django, layout, bootstrap-5, django-filter

I am currently working on my first bigger django project and I am facing issues regarding the layout of my data filters made with django-filters.
The default layout of the django-filter form is a vertical list (see image), but I need to make it horizontal, consisting of two rows (labels/fields).
[image]

What is the (best practice) way to edit the layout?
Is there a way I can access every Label/Field-Item of the form from within the template, so I can use Bootstrap5 Grid?

One restriction is, that my template will be used by differents models/filters, so I need to configure the layout dynamically.

Every hint is very much appreciated :)
Thank you!

My template (relevant section)

```html
<form method="get" class="form">
       <button type="submit" class ="btn btn-primary">Filtern</button>
       {% crispy filter.form %}
</form>
```

my django-filter filter class

```py
class EquipmentFilter(FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Equipment
        fields = {'name': ['icontains'], 'description': ['icontains']}
```

my model

```py
class Equipment(models.Model):
    """Device that can execute a measurement"""
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField("Description", max_length=100)
    configuration = models.JSONField("Configuration", default=dict)
    equipment_category = models.ForeignKey("EquipmentCategory", on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Equipment Category")
```

Answer (score 4):

`filter.form` is a normal Django form, so you can layout it the way you want.

I see that you use crispy forms. But you can style it anyway you want, boostrap-way included.

Here is an example from the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates)

You can use the `.as_p` method to get them in `<p><label><input></label></p>` format or you can generate them by hand:

```html
<form method="get" class="form">
  <button type="submit" class ="btn btn-primary">Filtern</button>
  {{ filter.form.non_field_errors }}
  <div class="boostrap-class">
    {{ filter.form.name.errors }}
    <label for="{{ filter.form.name.id_for_label }}" class="another-boostrap-class">Name</label>
    {{ filter.form.name }}
  </div>
  <div class="boostrap-class">
    {{ filter.form.description.errors }}
    <label for="{{ filter.form.description.id_for_label }}" class="another-boostrap-class">Description</label>
    {{ filter.form.description }}
  </div>
</form>
```

You can also specify a custom `Form` class in your filterset meta (`EquipmentFilter.Meta`) and use techniques presented in [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29716023/add-class-to-form-field-django-modelform)

Comment: thank you for your reply!

`{{ filter.form.name }}` does not seem to work for me.  It's not displaying the input fields of the filter. Furthermore I would need to access the fiels directly by name (eg: form.name or form.description). Is there a way to access the list/dict of labels/inputs dynamically?

I will give the custom form a try. As far  as I understand I could add the row / col classes of bootstrap grid to the form elements to achive my desired layout, right?

Comment: @toto290 yes it’s the general idea. I’m not familiar with the construct `fields = {'name': ['icontains'], 'description': ['icontains']}` but probably the filter form name is `name__icontains` and `description__icontains` respectively.

Comment: From reading `django-filter` [source code](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/blob/dbc69e76cf829836e5c65ee4219d7f123fcc69ff/django_filters/filterset.py#L303), that seams the case for filter names.

Answer (score 0):

I use class based views, my solution is to override `get_context_data` and massage the form there:

```
class EquipmentListView(
       SingleTableMixin,
       FilterView):

    model = Equipment
    table_class = EquipmentTable
    template_name = 'equipment/tables2/list.html'
    filterset_class = EquipmentFilter

    # override get_context_data
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        filter = context['filter']
        form = filter.form             # <- here!
        form.helper = FormHelper()
        form.helper.add_input(
            Submit('submit', 'Filter', css_class='btn-primary')
        )
        return context
```