# Problems with jquery/select2 framework - it doesn't work in my django project

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

i'm newbie in python, still learning this language and django framework. So i making simple project now, and now i meet this problem: i can't modify my design cause select2 and jquery not working in html document. Here is my files:

base.html

```html
{% url 'cities:home' as cities_home_url%}
{% url 'cities:create' as cities_create_url%}
{% url 'trains:home' as trains_home_url%}
{% url 'trains:create' as trains_create_url%}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="ar" dir="rtl">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-+4j30LffJ4tgIMrq9CwHvn0NjEvmuDCOfk6Rpg2xg7zgOxWWtLtozDEEVvBPgHqE" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
     {{ form.media.css }}
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg container" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home'%}">FindRoute</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
                aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item {% if request.path == cities_home_url%}active {% endif %}">
                    <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="{% url 'cities:home'%}">Города</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" {% if request.path== trains_home_url%}active {% endif %}>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'trains:home'%}">Поезда</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item dropdown"
                    {% if request.path== cities_create_url or request.path== trains_create_url %} active {% endif %}
                >
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                       aria-expanded="false">
                        Добавить
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'cities:create'%}">Новый город</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'trains:create'%}">Новый поезд</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 mx-auto my-4">
            {% if messages %}
            {% for message in messages %}
            {% if message.level == DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS.ERROR %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                {{ message }}
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            {% else %}
            <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                {{ message }}
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</div>
<!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

<!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
    $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
});
</script>
{{ form.media.js }}
</body>
</html>
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from cities.models import City


class RouteForm(forms.Form):
    from_city = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        label='Откуда', queryset=City.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(
            attrs={ 'class': 'form-control js-example-basic-single' }))
    to_city = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        label='Куда', queryset=City.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(
            attrs={'class': 'form-control js-example-basic-single'}))
    cities = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        label='Через города', queryset=City.objects.all(), required=False,
        widget=forms.SelectMultiple(
            attrs={'class': 'form-control js-example-basic-multiple'}
        )
    )
    travelling_time = forms.IntegerField(label='Время в пути', widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Время в пути'
        }))
```

settings.py

```
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_select2',
    'routes',
    'cities',
    'trains',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'travel.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'travel.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

import routes
from routes.views import home

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('cities/', include(('cities.urls', 'cities'))),
    path('trains/', include(('trains.urls', 'trains'))),
    path('', home, name='home'),
    path("select2/", include("django_select2.urls")),
]
```

So i'll so grateful if somebody helps me!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to use JQuery / select2 in HTML, you can do something like this.

`page.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ar" dir="rtl">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->
<select class="js-example-basic-single" name="state">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
      ...
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
<!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It may be that your forms.py doesn't set the class `js-example-basic-single` properly. If this is the case, [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29716023/add-class-to-form-field-django-modelform) may be able to further assist you.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: dear Tim, maybe i something not understand, cause i got script at the bottom of body: 
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
    $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Please look at my improved answer. I tried using your template code to see what was wrong with select2, but everything seemed to work fine (with some tweaks).
Hopefully my imporved answer can help you some more.

Answer (score 0):

it works for me in the following way

layout.html

```
<head>    
<link href="{% static 'select2/css/select2.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="{% static 'select2/css/select2-bootstrap4.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
...
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="{% static 'select2/js/select2.js' %}"></script>
      <script src="{% static 'select2/js/i18n/es.js' %}"></script>
      <script>

        $('.select2').select2({
            theme: "bootstrap4",
            language: 'es'
        });
        
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('select[name="selector"]').select2();
        });
        </script>
</body>
```

in form.py

```
class ExampleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Example
        fields = '__all__'        
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control' }),
            'exampleselect': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control select2'}),
        }
```

in templates/example/example_form.html

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %} 
            <div class="mb-3">               
                {{form}}
            </div>            
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary text-center">Save</button>
          </form>
```